# Something went wrong installing Haskell failed to install ghc

Tags: haskell, ghc

> ghc-8.6.5/compiler/stage2/build/libHSghc-8.6.5-ghc8.6.5.dylib: Lzma library error:  No progress is possible
>   tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
>   unpacking failed!
>   Failed to install, consider updating this script via: ghcup upgrade
>   "ghcup --cache install" failed!

I'm installing the GHC by using

> curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://get-ghcup.haskell.org | sh

My Internet cut and I had to shut down the terminal and rerun the program. I now get this error. It seems some file package was corrupt but I'm not sure how to find and delete the corrupt files manually or if there is some other way to repair the installation?

Answer (score 1):

You have a partially downloaded, and thus corrupted, file in `~/.ghcup/cache/`. Delete it and rerun ghcup.